# Bus seat calculation dynamic algorithm with variation in stops

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, logic

Given the database result below,

- A null value in BusStopNumber denotes to Origin which in Mogadishu in this case
- A null value in BusStopNumber2 denotes to Destination which in Nairobi in this case

If are a total of 10 seats on a bus.

What is the best way to calculate the number of seats left when a passenger wants to travel from Mogadishu to Hargeisa (Which is the final stop before the destination) and we have 2 Seats booked from Initial point to final Point? Similarly, I want to calculate seats available from the SeatsCount column which denotes how many seats have been booked for all routes.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @booking table
(
    id int identity,
    busid int,
    scheduleid int,
    stopnumber smallint,
    stopnumber2 smallint,
    seatscount smallint
);

insert into @booking(busid, scheduleid, stopnumber, stopnumber2, seatscount)
values 
(1, 6, null, null, 2),
(1, 6, null, 1, 2),
(1, 6, null, 2, 1),
(1, 6, null, 3, 2),
(1, 6, 1, null, 2),
(1, 6, 1, 2, 1),
(1, 6, 1, 3, 1),
(1, 6, 2, null, 1),
(1, 6, 2, 3, 1),
(1, 6, 3, null, 2);

select * from @booking;


select *, 
--total number of passengers that got on the bus at previous&current stops
(select isnull(sum(e.seatscount), 0) from @booking as e where e.busid = b.busid and e.scheduleid = b.scheduleid and isnull(e.stopnumber, 0) <= isnull(b.stopnumber, 0))
-
--total number of passengers that got off the bus at previous&current stops
(select isnull(sum(d.seatscount), 0) from @booking as d where d.busid = b.busid and d.scheduleid = b.scheduleid and d.stopnumber2 <= b.stopnumber)
as PassengersOnBusAtStopNumber
from @booking as b;
```

Comment: This seems genius but having an issue as below https://ibb.co/9v6BxcZ as you can see in row number 2 there were only 2 seats on a particular stops rest should be 2 throughout the route but Destination to all stops were occupied

Comment: PassengersOnBusAtStopNumber is the number of passengers on the bus right before the departure (right before bus leaves stopnumber). You could follow a similar logic (slightly different math) and calculate the number of passengers right before the bus arrives at stopnumber2.
All this, assuming that seatscount is the number of seats booked (and/or occupied) for the route from stopnumber-->stopnumber2. For your first comment: Row1:2 seatscount for NULL-NULL (the bus will have at least 2 occupied seats for the whole route). Row2:  2 seatscount for NULL - 1. PassengersOnBusAtStopNumber[NULL] = 4

Comment: Row2 {2 seatscount for NULL - 1}also means that those two persons get off at stopnumber = 1. From Row3 and on, seatscount = 0 --> no bookings--> no passengers get on the bus, thus PassengersOnBusAtStopNumber[1], [2], [3] = 2 (4 persons initially at the very departure - 2 persons got off at stopnumber1), yet again, i am assuming seatscount is the number of persons on the bus or to get on the bus, seatscount = booked seats for the specific route (from stopnumber till stopnumber2)

Comment: Hey I got your phenomena which is accurately correct logically Thankyou for your time and perfect solution.

Comment: you are welcome. By calculating the passengers on bus at every stopnumber(every departure) you can figure out how many seats are availabe for a specific route: Lets say, all your info are prebookings (the bus has not left the Mogadishu station yet). A person wants to travel from Bossaso(stop:1) to Nairobi (stopnumber2 = null), The number of seats available for route:@1 to @NULL is: 'BusSeats(constant:10) - MAX(PassengersOnBusAtStopNumber) FROM (..query..)  as av where av.busid=1 and av.scheduleid=1 and isnull(av.stopnumber, 0) >= @1 and (av.stopnumber < @NULL  or @NULL is null) `